# Is it possible to enforce non-nullability of LiveData values?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

Is there any way to enforce non-nullability of LiveData values? Default Observer implementation seems to have @Nullable annotation which forces an IDE to suggest that the value might be null and should be checked manually:

```
public interface Observer<T> {
    /**
     * Called when the data is changed.
     * @param t  The new data
     */
    void onChanged(@Nullable T t);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there a few things you can do, it is your responsibility to make sure you don't pass `null` to the `LiveData`. In addition to that, every 'solution' is more a suppression of the warning, which can be dangerous (if you do get a null value, you might not handle it and Android Studio will not warn you).

### Assert

You can add `assert t != null;`. The assert will not be executed on Android, but Android Studio understands it.

```java
class PrintObserver implements Observer<Integer> {

    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable Integer integer) {
        assert integer != null;
        Log.d("Example", integer.toString());
    }
}
```

### Suppress the warning

Add an annotation to suppress the warning.

```java
class PrintObserver implements Observer<Integer> {

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
    public void onChanged(@Nullable Integer integer) {
        Log.d("Example", integer.toString());
    }
}
```

### Remove the annotation

This also works in my installation of Android Studio, but it might not work for you, but you could try to just remove the `@Nullable` annotation from the implementation:

```java
class PrintObserver implements Observer<Integer> {

    @Override
    public void onChanged(Integer integer) {
        Log.d("Example", integer.toString());
    }
}
```

### Default methods

It's unlikely you can use this on Android, but purely from a Java perspective, you could define a new interface and add a null check in a default method:

```java
interface NonNullObserver<V> extends Observer<V> {

    @Override
    default void onChanged(@Nullable V v) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(v);
        onNonNullChanged(v);
        // Alternatively, you could add an if check here.
    }

    void onNonNullChanged(@NonNull V value);
}
```

Comment: Yea, it looks like the only thing we can do for now is to use workarounds. Thanks for describing the most common approaches!

Answer (score 12):

A new option is available if you use `Kotlin`. You can replace `LiveData` with [StateFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-state-flow/). It is more suitable for `Kotlin` code and provides built-in null safety.

Instead of using:

```kotlin
class MyViewModel {
    val data: LiveData<String> = MutableLiveData(null) // the compiler will allow null here!
}

class MyFragment: Fragment() {
    model.data.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can use:

```kotlin
class MyViewModel {
    val data: StateFlow<String> = MutableStateFlow(null) // compilation error!
}

class MyFragment: Fragment() {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        model.data.collect {
          // ...
        }
    }
}
```

`StateFlow` is part of [coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html) and to use the `lifecycleScope` you need to add the `lifecycle-extensions` dependency:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
```

Note that this API has been experimental before [coroutines 1.4.0](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/10/kotlinx-coroutines-1-4-0-introducing-stateflow-and-sharedflow/?mkt_tok=eyJpIjoiTUdJeFltWTBZV1psTXpReiIsInQiOiI4b2NkVFJKeGJnMXZYc1RmQWNERFlCekU0UVF0RzhFa054bDhQVkgxWXhUbmNLckFOTmVhVlgzdnYrb0wzOFl2Ym52b3hqQ05KMzNqSVV0ekVTQmJiTWExYVhPSGp6TUV3SGVZeFZ5RE8xVVlMU2xsb3hGU3J4cTU0a1c3TDFzeSJ9).

[Here's](https://medium.com/scalereal/stateflow-end-of-livedata-a473094229b3) some additional reading about replacing `LiveData` with `StateFlow`.

As [Igor Bubelov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1042342/igor-bubelov) pointed out, another advantage of this approach is that it's not `Android` specific so it can be used in shared code in multiplatform projects.

Comment: That's what I've been using lately and I like it too. Bonus points: coroutines (and flows) aren't Android specific which allows us to use the same tools in backend/multiplatform mobile projects. It's easy to use, it's more generic and there are no performance or convenience penalties so it seems like a better option.

Comment: You're absolutely right. This is also one of the reasons why I'm using it. I'll add a note to the answer.

Comment: I needed implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version", thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/56035529/7439163

Answer (score 6):

It's possible to do it safely only if you are in control of the code which sets the data because you'll also have to wrap the `LiveData` class. This way the data setting methods will be protected with `@NonNull` and you can be sure that the data has already been checked before reaching the `Observer`.

Wrap the `LiveData` class:

```
public class NonNullMutableLiveData<T> extends MutableLiveData<T> implements NonNullLiveData<T> {

    private final @NonNull T initialValue;

    public NonNullMutableLiveData(@NonNull T initialValue) {
        this.initialValue = initialValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void postValue(@NonNull T value) {
        super.postValue(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(@NonNull T value) {
        super.setValue(value);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public T getValue() {
        //the only way value can be null is if the value hasn't been set yet.
        //for the other cases the set and post methods perform nullability checks.
        T value = super.getValue();
        return value != null ? value : initialValue;
    }

    //convenience method
    //call this method if T is a collection and you modify it's content
    public void notifyContentChanged() {
        postValue(getValue());
    }

    public void observe(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner, @NonNull NonNullObserver<T> observer) {
        super.observe(owner, observer.getObserver());
    }
}
```

Create an interface for exposing as immutable:

```
public interface NonNullLiveData<T> {

    @NonNull T getValue();

    void observe(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner, @NonNull NonNullObserver<T> observer);
}
```

Finally, wrap the `Observer`:

```
//not implementing Observer<T> to make sure this class isn't passed to
//any class other than NonNullMutableLiveData.
public abstract class NonNullObserver<T> {

    public Observer<T> getObserver() {
        return new ActualObserver();
    }

    public abstract void onValueChanged(@NonNull T t);

    private class ActualObserver implements Observer<T> {

        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable T t) {
            //only called through NonNullMutableLiveData so nullability check has already been performed.
            //noinspection ConstantConditions
            onValueChanged(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can create your data like this:

```
class DataSource {
    private NonNullMutableLiveData<Integer> data = new NonNullMutableLiveData<>(0);

    public NonNullLiveData<Integer> getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
dataSource.getData().observe(this, new NonNullObserver<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChanged(@NonNull Integer integer) {

            }
        });
```

Completely `null` safe.

Answer (score 5):

If you use Kotlin, you can create much nicer non-null observe function with extension. There is an article about it. https://medium.com/@henrytao/nonnull-livedata-with-kotlin-extension-26963ffd0333

Comment: Do you have the java version of that?

Comment: Hmmmm. I can add Java version but you won't have nice looking usage like Kotlin, simply because Java does not have extension function.

Comment: Downvote for forcing the LiveData to be null-safe. It is nullable because at the time of access LiveData might not have any value yet

Answer (score 3):

```
fun <T> LiveData<T>.observeNonNull(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: (t: T) -> Unit) {
    this.observe(owner, Observer {
        it?.let(observer)
    })
}
```

Comment: hie! metis! wouldn't it be great that you add some text to the answer! the answer seems legit, but a little more English explanation will bring more audience to find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do some additional work to handle null values that come from the library itself.

For example, when you return a `LiveData` from a `@Dao` in Room, like:

```
@Dao interface UserDao {

    @get:Query("SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1")
    val user: LiveData<User>

}
```

And observe the `user` live data, it will call the `onChanged` callback with a `null` value if there is no user.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a nullable LiveData to a non-nullable LiveData, use [Transformation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#transform_livedata).
Example on Kotlin:

```kotlin
val eventsList: LiveData<List<Event>> = Transformations.map(dao.getEvents()) { list ->
            list ?: emptyList()
}
```

`dao.getEvents()` return data with type `List<Event>?`, then `Transformations` return empty `List<Event>!` if list is null.