# How to get lifecycle.coroutineScope with new androidx.lifecycle:*:2.2.0-alpha01

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

On 7th May, 2019 `androidx.lifecycle:*:2.2.0-alpha01` was released announcing:

> This release adds new features that adds support for Kotlin coroutines for Lifecycle and LiveData. Detailed documentation on them can be found here.

On [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope) it's mentioned that I can get the `LifecycleScope`:

> either via `lifecycle.coroutineScope` or `lifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope` properties

But it seems that I'm not able to find none of them. My current dependencises are:

```
def lifecycle_ver = "2.2.0-alpha01"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_ver"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_ver"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_ver"

implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.2.1'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.2.1'
```

What may be the cause and how do get these apis?

Comment: you can find the relevant versions here

, https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.lifecycle/lifecycle-extensions/2.0.0-alpha1

, https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.lifecycle/lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx/2.0.0-alpha1

, https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.lifecycle/lifecycle-common-java8/2.0.0-alpha1

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I actually spent a couple hours trying to figure this out myself and it turns out it is in a new package that only exists as of the alpha.  Add this and you should be good to go.

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_ver"
```

Comment: Are you sure you did that exact line? I pulled up the source for it and have my own code running with it using lifecycleScope.  What is it doing when you add it and try to reference lifecycleScope from a lifecycleOwner?

Comment: Even in an activity you should be able to do lifecycle.lifecycleScope since the activity is a lifecycle owner.  What error is it giving you when you add the runtime-ktx dependency?

Comment: Thanks, works for me. Just use `lifecycleScope.launch {...}` from acrivity

Comment: My bad, didn't noticed `-ktx` at end, you should also edit the answer and mention the same. Wasted a whole day :p

Comment: OMG. I'm searching for this for hours! This works.

(The jetpack / ktx documentation is absolutely miserable. So many different sites but none shows a clear list of available packages and versions. Shame on you jetpack team!)

Comment: Source: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#dependencies

Comment: How come I still fail to get it ? I tried it for this : https://androidexplained.github.io/android/ui/2020/10/21/improving-textview-settext-performance.html . For some reason, no matter what I add to gradle, I can't get `lifecycleScope` to be used at all...

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answers is working, but I'm misused for the first time, so I'm trying to make it clear, the current version of `lifecycle` is `"2.1.0"` and `lifecycleScope`, and `ViewModelScope` is not available in this version, to get them use

For **ViewModelScope**,

use `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.1.0-beta01` or higher.

For **LifecycleScope**,

use `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0-alpha01` or higher.

at this time `2.4.1` is available.

Answer (score 1):

Try this line of code in Build.Gradle (App Level)

```
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just added this two lines of code to my build.gradle (App) and that worked like a charm. I can import lifecycleScope without any problems.

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.2'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.2'
```