# Unable to use Lifecycle Version 2.2.0-alpha01 features

Tags: android, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

I am attempting to integrate some of the features presented [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines) in my kotlin android app. I am able to use the `viewModelScope` fine in my ViewModels, although this only works when including `implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.1.0-alpha09"` in my dependencies.

However, I am completely unable to use the `liveData` builder function highlighted in [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata) section. When attempting to use `liveData` within my ViewModel, I get an unresolved reference error.

I have attempted the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56035176/how-to-get-lifecycle-coroutinescope-with-new-androidx-lifecycle2-2-0-alpha01) thread, but that doesn't solve my problem.

This is the relevant section of my build.gradle file with all of the dependencies related to ViewModel and LiveData

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0-alpha01"

// ViewModel and LiveData
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:1.0.0-alpha01"
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.1.0-alpha09"
```

It's worth mentioning again that I can't use `viewModelScope` either without including `implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.1.0-alpha09"` in my dependencies.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I've done a bit of searching but can't find much as this is a relatively recent release. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, it seems like the 
`implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"` 
line doesn't work here nor does 
`implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"`, 
and we need to declare dependencies for the kotlin versions of ViewModel and LiveData individually. The following is the updated dependencies section for ViewModel and LiveData (note the absence of the fragment dependency as well!)

```
// ViewModel and LiveData
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:1.0.0-alpha01"
kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
```

With the above I am now able to use `viewModelScope` and the `liveData` builder function mentioned in the question post.