# Is LiveData null safe in Kotlin? Why can Android Studio compile it?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack

In my mind, Kotlin is null safe.

The Code A is from the project Universal Android Music Player Sample, you can see [here](https://github.com/android/uamp)

It seems that `val rootMediaId: LiveData<String>` is not null safe in Code A, a null string can be assigned to `rootMediaId`, I don't know why Android Studio can compile these code, could you tell me?

I think that the Code B is reputable code.

**Code A**

```
viewModel.rootMediaId.observe(this,
                Observer<String> { rootMediaId ->
                    if (rootMediaId != null) {
                        navigateToMediaItem(rootMediaId)
                    }
                })



class MainActivityViewModel(
    private val musicServiceConnection: MusicServiceConnection
) : ViewModel() {

    val rootMediaId: LiveData<String> =
        Transformations.map(musicServiceConnection.isConnected) { isConnected ->
            if (isConnected) {
                musicServiceConnection.rootMediaId
            } else {
                null
            }
        }
   ...
}
```

**Code B**

```
class MainActivityViewModel(
    private val musicServiceConnection: MusicServiceConnection
) : ViewModel() {

    val rootMediaId: LiveData<String?> =
        Transformations.map(musicServiceConnection.isConnected) { isConnected ->
            if (isConnected) {
                musicServiceConnection.rootMediaId
            } else {
                null
            }
        }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Java Platform Types in Kotlin are ***not null-safe, by design***. It's unfortunate, I'd prefer to write `!` to force-unwrap them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because Live Data is written in Java so Kotlin uses platform type here. You can read more about it [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types). In two words: Java types don't contain nullability information so Kolin cannot infer the correct type. `String` from Java can be `String` or `String?` in Kotlin. Android studio marks such `String` types as `String!` so you can pay attention and set appropriate type by yourself.

Comment: Thanks! Is Code B  `val rootMediaId: LiveData<String?>`  better way?

Comment: @HelloCW if you know that data can be nullable then definitely yes

Answer (score 1):

Andrei Tanana's answer describes the general situation. But specifically for `LiveData`, note that `getValue()` (or `value` in Kotlin) is nullable and so [typed as `T?` in Kotlin](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData). So in a sense it doesn't matter whether the result is typed as `LiveData<String>` or `LiveData<String?>`; the values you get from it are `String?` either way.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46488442/is-it-possible-to-enforce-non-nullability-of-livedata-values) also states `Observer` takes `T?`, but this doesn't seem to be reflected [in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/Observer).